# Truncated Output from Nodejs ssh2-exec

Tags: node.js, ssh2-exec

Can someone please help me understand why the ssh command output is getting truncated when using `result[ip] = data.toString();` but not `console.log(data.toString());`? I only get the first 50 bytes or so for the object assignment, but console.log gets everything. The reason I'm using Promise/await is because I'm planning to eventually have this reach out to several hosts simultaneously and get the results using Promise.all before moving on.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node
var fs = require('fs');
var ssh_client = require('ssh2').Client;


var ssh_config = {
    port: 22,
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    readyTimeout: 5000 };
var cmd = 'find /home/username -type f -iname "*.txt"';


async function main() {
    let ip = '10.10.10.110';
    let result = await sshExec(ip);
    console.log(result[ip]);
}


function sshExec(ip) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let ssh = new ssh_client();
        let config = Object.assign(ssh_config, {'host': ip});
        let result = {};

        ssh.connect(config);

        ssh.on('ready', function() {
            console.log("Connected to " + ip + ".");
            ssh.exec(cmd, function(err, stream) {
                if (err) throw err;
                stream.on('data', function(data) {
                    //console.log(data.toString());
                    result[ip] = data.toString();
                }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
                    console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
                }).on('close', function(code, signal) {
                    ssh.end();
                });
            });
        });

        ssh.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log(ip + ', connection failed, ' + e.message);
        });

        ssh.on('close', function(hadError) {
            if (!hadError) {
                console.log('Connection to ' + ip + ' closed without errors.');
                resolve(result);
            }
            else {
                console.log('Connection to ' + ip + ' closed with errors.');
                reject(result.ip = 'failure');
            }
        });
    });
}


main();
```

Comment: Are you certain that `result[ip]` only gets the _first_ part of the output?  My guess is that the `data` event fires multiple times, so `result[ip]` retains only the output from the _last_ `data` event.  Check by having `console.log` in the `data` handler add a prefix string to the received string, so you see that prefix every time the `data` event fires. If that's the problem then to fix do `result[ip] = "";` immediately after `let result = {};` and do `result[ip] += data.toString();` in the `data` handler. Also, `reject(result.ip = ...` should be `reject(result[ip] = ...`.

Comment: That was exactly it. Thank you so much!